# When iam trying to run spring example i am facing the following exception

Tags: java, spring

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [spring.test.StockValueFetcher] for bean with name 'stockBean' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spring.test.StockValueFetcher
```

and my applicationContext.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>

<bean id="stockBean" class="spring.test.StockValueFetcher">
</bean>

</beans>
```

i have searched for the same in stackoverflow and other sites but i couldnot find any helpful solution

Comment: It's a basic Java problem: ClassNotFoundException is thrown because the class loader can't find your spring.test.StockValueFetcher.  You can't use Spring well unless you actually understand Java.

Comment: is there any class named by  `StockValueFetcher` in your application?

Comment: Which IDE.. check whether source folder is defined in classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of below two possibilities:

1. Check your build/classes folder. Does it have the class file for "StockValueFetcher" in the appropriate package.
2. If you are using MAVEN, have you added "Maven Dependencies" to the project's "Web Deployment Assembly". If not, add that as follows (assuming you are using Eclipse):

Right Click on your project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Java Build Path Entries -> Next and then from there you can add "maven Dependencies". Then build and try to run your app.

Answer (score 2):

2 possible causes

1. Your class isn't called StockValueFetcher or isn't declared in the package spring.test
2. Your class is not properly deployed and/or defined in the webserver application

It is easy to validate 1.

In case it is 1: correct the spring config file
In case it is 2: check your build & deploy procedure to correctly create the proper web application